# What is the purpose of the 'self' parameter in Python's builtins.print()?

Tags: python, built-in

Being new to Python, I was looking for the implementation of the built-in `print()` function. Following the "Go to implementation" feature of my IDE, I landed in a `builtins.py` file containing function prototypes - and the `print()` function particularly stood out:

```py
def print(self, *args, sep=' ', end='\n', file=None): # known special case of print
```

It was the only function of the whole section that made use of the `self` parameter. Why? It's never called as a member of an object and you never assign to that attribute either. What purpose does it serve?

Comment: Where exactly did you find that file? The built-in `print` function is just that: a *function* (not a method) that is built into the interpreter, not defined in Python itself.

Comment: This may be special to your IDE.

Comment: In some sense, the name `self` doesn't imply that it's a method; but the built-in `print` function doesn't have any required positional arguments, which is what this definition describes. (I.e., `print()` is valid; you don't have to pass at least one positional argument.)

Comment: The actual signature of [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is `print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`

Comment: Here is commit which introduced this change: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/commit/d3d348faa838e7dba79fef8c1a52c08c7cc77d9e#diff-6490e7337b6eebc2f981f10bed59e80eR14 and issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18275. Though I'm not sure why did they include `self` in `print`, it looks like a mistake to me, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Also FWIW here's the [source code for CPython's `print`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1826)

Comment: Looking through the resources posted here, is it possible it's a kind PyCharm's workaround for correctly handling hints in some scenarios?

Comment: Yes, probably. But it is still unclear for me why did they change `print`, while issue only mentions `format` method. They also did not include `print` in test cases, so it is hard to say what case (if any) were they trying to fix.

Answer (score 0):

`__init__` and in this init function we use SELF and this allows the class to initialize the attributes of the class. `__init__` is also a reserved method in classes it is a **constructor** in **OOP** *(Object Oriented/Object Oriented Programming)* concept:

```py
class Test():
  HELLO = "Hello World!"
  def __init__(self,HELLO):
    self.HELLO = "Hello World? I guess.."

x = Test()
print(x.HELLO) // prints Hello World? I guess..
print(Test.HELLO) // prints Hello World!
```

Usually it is our practice to write the `__init__` method for setting the default state of an(the) *attribute* with SELF

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! While I appreciate you took the time to write an answer... I'm afraid you misunderstood my question. I understand the concept of OOP and the `self` parameter in Python in general - that's why I was caught off-guard by a _function_ (not a _method_) having the `self` parameter as well. The `builtins` function [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) should have no `self` parameter after all.

Comment: Ah ok sorry I misunderstood then like you said